# Class Component with new kotlin-react without legacy

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

The kotlin-wrappers for React was split into kotlin-react and kotlin-react-legacy in version pre.282.

In kotlin-react-legacy it is possible to create a class based component by using RComponent.
This is missing in the new kotlin-react, however both kotlin-react and kotlin-react-legacy import kotlin-react-core which contains Component.

In kotlin-react-legacy the RComponent is defined by using RBuilder, but that doesn't exist in kotlin-react which instead has ChildrenBuilder. It would be possible to create something analogous to the legacy RComponent with ChildrenBuilder, however it cannot be accessed because it is internal.

Is there any way to create a class-based React Component, similar to what is possible in kotlin-react-legacy with RComponent, in the new kotlin-react?

Answer (score 1):

There is a related discussion: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/issues/1266

Which mentions a working example: https://github.com/studoverse/campus-qr/blob/master/moderatorFrontend/src/main/kotlin/webcore/ReactHelper.kt

The RComponent can be defined as follows:

```
abstract class RComponent<P : Props, S : State> : Component<P, S> {
    constructor() : super() {
        state = jso { init() }
    }

    constructor(props: P) : super(props) {
        state = jso { init(props) }
    }

    open fun S.init() {}

    // if you use this method, don't forget to pass props to the constructor first
    open fun S.init(props: P) {}

    abstract fun ChildrenBuilder.render()

    override fun render(): ReactNode = Fragment.create { render() }
}

fun <S : State> Component<*, S>.setState(buildState: S.() -> Unit) {
    val partialState: S = jso {
        buildState()
    }
    setState(partialState)
}
```

Then a component can be created as:

```
class TestComponent : RComponent<Props, State>() {
    override fun ChildrenBuilder.render() {
        div {
            +"Hello, world!"
        }
    }
}
```

And instantiated:

```
TestComponent::class.react {}
```